# PHP: Getting specific data in array

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs

I can't get the value of my array . Please help me. I'am using angularjs and php slim framework.

this is my code in PHP:

```
function testArray(){
$app = Slim::getInstance();   
$app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
$post = json_decode($app->request()->getBody());
$data = get_object_vars($post);


echo json_encode(array_values($data['name']));}
```

This is my code in controller and factory:

```
app.controller('fooCtrl', ['$scope', 'adminFactory', function($scope, adminFactory) {
$scope.arr = [{name:"rence"}, {name:"asd"}, {name:"qwe"}, {name:"qwe"}]; //your array
adminFactory.sendData($scope.arr).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});}]);


adminFactory.sendData = function(arr) {
    return $http({
        withCredentials: false,
        method: 'post',
        url: urlBase + '/test',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: {'arr': arr}
    });
};
```

I'am getting an error from php. 500 (Internal Server Error). Thank you!

Comment: what does `$data` contain.

Comment: I use json_decode method post to contain the value from factory and controller $scope.arr

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting json at server but you added header for `form-urlencoded`

Remove the `headers` from `$http`.

Also you have to serialize the data yourself to send form encoded

Comment: still not work. don't know what to do in this line: $mynames = array_values($data['name']); .. is my line is correct ? I'am going to serialize the object in array.  Sorry I am newbie in PHP. thank you for your answer.